# Extreme temperature quick disconnect terminals

Tags: electrical-engineering, material-science

I am doing R&D work and am in need of terminals that can withstand 1,000 degrees Celsius, but cannot seem to find anything anywhere.  The highest temperature ratings I have found are around 600 degrees Celsius.  The terminals will be used in a furnace like enclosure.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can please share a links to the 600 degrees Celsius terminals you found?

Comment: https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/high_temperature_temp_terms_terminals